# How to connect swift codes and storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I am trying to figure out a way to use the Pod ColorMatchTabs, however its example is doing it programmatically and I can't find a way to use them in my project. I will summarize this:

To use the pod, I have to follow this protocols to install the tabs in my viewController:

```
extension ExampleViewController: ColorMatchTabsViewControllerDataSource {
    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, iconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].normalImage
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, hightlightedIconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].highlightedImage
    }



    func numberOfItems(inController controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController) -> Int {
        return TabItemsProvider.items.count
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, viewControllerAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
        return StubContentViewControllersProvider.viewControllers[index]
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, titleAt index: Int) -> String {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].title
    }

    func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, tintColorAt index: Int) -> UIColor {
        return TabItemsProvider.items[index].tintColor
    }
```

These are the protocols to handle how the tabs look like, how many items and my difficulties are in the part calling UIViewController. I assume it return which controllers are used based on which tab, and here goes the code in `StubContentViewControllersProvider`:

```
import UIKit
import ColorMatchTabs

class StubContentViewControllersProvider {

    static let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = {


        let productsViewController = StubContentViewController()

        productsViewController.type = .products

        let venuesViewController = StubContentViewController()
        venuesViewController.type = .venues

        let reviewsViewController = StubContentViewController()
        reviewsViewController.type = .reviews

        let usersViewController = StubContentViewController()
        usersViewController.type = .users

        return [productsViewController, venuesViewController, reviewsViewController, usersViewController]
    }()

}
```

I assume we are calling all the controllers from `StubContentViewController` and here is how it looks like:

```
import UIKit

class StubContentViewController: UITableViewController {

    enum `Type` {
        case products, venues, reviews, users
    }

    var type: Type!

    fileprivate var objects: [UIImage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        setupTableView()
        setupDataSource()
    }

    fileprivate func setupTableView() {
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExampleTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    fileprivate func setupDataSource() {
        if type == .products || type == .reviews {
            self.objects = [UIImage(named: "product_card1")!, UIImage(named: "product_card2")!]
        } else if type == .venues || type == .users {
            self.objects = [UIImage(named: "venue_card1")!, UIImage(named: "venue_card2")!]
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExampleTableViewCell
        let image = objects[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.apply(image)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.bounds.width / 1.4
    }


}
```

So my question here is, I am setting up a TableViewController and reference it to `StubContentViewController` in storyboard, but why when I make changes in the storyboard, it doesn't make any effect? And for example I want to perform a segue for the table cell, I couldn't find any way to make it via the storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard is a way to design the way your app should navigate from one view controller to another. You can create a segue from your table view cell selection to another view controller by control dragging from the cell to another view controller. So when the user taps on the cell it would navigate to the other view controller

Comment: But according to the codes above, I should create a viewcontroller in my storyboard and reference it to StubContentViewController and create the segue right? However it just look like the stubcontentviewcontroller in the storyboard is not connecting to the one in codes.

Comment: Please don't paste only relevant code, it is difficult to read through all that code and expect someone to answer your question. So edit your question to make it precise.

Comment: Set the class of the view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: I tried that, and created a segue to another view controller, and added `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRestaurant", sender: self)` to the table cell, however I received this error `Receiver has no segue with identifier 'showRestaurant'` . So my guess was that storyboard and codes are not connected..

Comment: When you create a segue in storyboard you have to give it an identifier. Have you set it ?

Comment: Yup I have set it to `showRestaurant` too, thats why I posted the codes in my question, is it because I called `StubContentViewController()`, which means it doesn't go through storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144729/discussion-between-user1046037-and-pyfl88).